# How can i slove this problem?

Tags: complex-analysis

C={z| |z-1|=2} 
Integral c  1/(z^4+1) dz 
How can i do this? Please help

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use some theorems the answer is 0 and requires no calculation. All the roots are inside $|z-1|=2$ and hence the integral over $|z-1|=2$ coincides with the integral over $|z-1|=R$ for any $R>2$. The latter goes to 0 as $R \to \infty$. For a more direct argument one has to compute teh residue at each of the four simple poles. Tedious, but straightforward.